# How to use yolo3 with RTMP?

Tags: object-detection, rtmp, yolo

I want to detect objects in real-time with YOLO on RTMP.
I have used on this:https://github.com/MarcoBay/darknet-rtmp 
But when I use this, the error occurs as follows:

```
*darknet.exe detector demo cfg/coco.data yolo.cfg yolov3_gpu_4000.weights -dont_show -rtmp_fps 15 -rtmp_bps 2000000 rtmp://192.168.110.48:1935/live/001*
Demo
layer     filters    size              input                output
    0 TH conv     32  3 x 3 / 1   608 x 608 x   3   ->   608 x 608 x  32
    1 TH conv     64  3 x 3 / 2   608 x 608 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  64
    2 TH conv     32  1 x 1 / 1   304 x 304 x  64   ->   304 x 304 x  32
    3 TH conv     64  3 x 3 / 1   304 x 304 x  32   ->   304 x 304 x  64
    4 Shortcut Layer: 1
   ...
   95 route  91
   96 TH conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    38 x  38 x 256   ->    38 x  38 x 128
   97 upsample            2x    38 x  38 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 128
   98 route  97 36
   99 TH conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 384   ->    76 x  76 x 128
  100 TH conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256
  101 TH conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128
  102 TH conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256
  103 TH conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 128
  104 TH conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    76 x  76 x 128   ->    76 x  76 x 256
  105 TH conv    171  1 x 1 / 1    76 x  76 x 256   ->    76 x  76 x 171
  106 detection
Loading weights from yolov3_gpu_4000.weights...
 seen 64
Done!
video file: rtmp://192.168.110.48:1935/live/001
**Couldn't connect to webcam.
: Invalid argument**
```

How can I solve this problem?
Please help me with the experience with YOLO on RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your webcam connections/configuration the error is with the webcam connection, the model weights looks to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.
Webcam is correctly connected. 
When I use this program as webcam model, this error occurs.

detect size : w: 640, h: 480
[h264_qsv encoder @ 00000218f27d5080] [Eval @ 000000d9c2f3e820] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'superfast'
[h264_qsv encoder @ 00000218f27d5080] Unable to parse option value "superfast"
[h264_qsv encoder @ 00000218f27d5080] Error setting option preset to value superfast.
Could not open video encoder!